# OnLocationChange send coordinates to Firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a Capstone Project i badly need help got stuck on this for a few days now , i want to send an location updates to Firebase when the user Clicks on a button. Updates are set to send every 3 seconds on location change . But the problem is it only sends coordinates once the button is pressed and not continuously sends updates on location change. Here is my Code

```
Start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoc);
Stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopSend);

    mRef = new Firebase ("FIREBASE URL");

    Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                Firebase busCoords = mRef.child("Location");
                busCoords.setValue(location.getLatitude()+ ",   "+location.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            }
        };

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,1000,listener);
        }
    });

    Stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(locationManager != null){
                //noinspection MissingPermission
                locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Do you want this run as a service that continual runs when the app is closed or do you want it run only while the app is open?  I think that you may run into Activity Lifecycle issues here in Android.

Comment: my activity has two buttons, SEND and STOP . when user clicks on SEND it continuously send current location on every interval

Comment: Again, are you expecting to have this run while the activity is in the background or only while the activity is visible on the screen?  I think you are running into issues with the Activity Lifecycle.

Comment: while the activity is on screen

Comment: Are you running this on an emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that I see that are going on:

1)  Only the last recorded location is being recorded.  Where you have:

```
Firebase busCoords = mRef.child("Location");
busCoords.setValue(location.getLatitude()+ ",   "+location.getLongitude());
```

You should put:

```
Firebase busCoords = mRef.child("Location");
busCoords.push().setValue(location.getLatitude()+ ",   "+location.getLongitude());
```

This will push each new location as a list item to your Firebase database.

2)  It is possible that the distance between coordinates is too large as well:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,1000,listener);
```

This is expecting a distance of at least 1000 meters before it records another location.  You may want to consider changing that to 2 or 3 meter seperation for now while you are testing.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Use **GeoFire Api** provided by firebase to get location updates. In your `onLocationChanged()` method you have to do it like this.

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    geoFire.setLocation("location", new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
            if (error != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Location saved on server successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

This method will give you LatLong everytime it changes.

Comment: Thanks for the Help, may i know where shall i put the code on sending to my firebase,

Comment: Already written that onLocation changed method but before add geofire api in your project

Comment: where do i insert this ?  Firebase busCoords = mRef.child("Location");
                busCoords.setValue(location.getLatitude()+ ",   "+location.getLongitude());